# How to get a nymph rebirth in deva heavens?

Tags: buddha, deva

How exactly does that go down because I know male devas have nymphs.

Comment: The Buddha never taught to get anything. The Buddha taught us to loose everything in order to have true peace & happiness.

Answer (score 3):

- Practice Metta meditation and try not to get angry or upset.
- Speak kind words. Avoid harsh words, divisive words etc.
- Keep to the five precepts.
- Do good deeds like donations, alms givings etc. and wish to be a goddess(better than nymphs).

In short, practice the [ten moral actions](https://puredhamma.net/moral-living-and-fundamentals/ten-moral-actions-dasa-kusala/) and wish for heavenly birth.

By the  way, using Buddhism only to get a heavenly birth is like using a CT scan machine as a park bench or using a gold bar as a doorstop. Buddhism has a much higher happiness to offer than heavenly births.

Answer (score 1):

Make lots of money.

> Suppose, Māgandiya, a householder or a householder’s son was rich,
>   with great wealth and property, and being provided and endowed with
>   the five cords of sensual pleasure, he might enjoy himself with forms
>   cognizable by the eye…with sounds cognizable by the ear…with odours
>   cognizable by the nose…with flavours cognizable by the tongue…with
>   tangibles cognizable by the body that are wished for, desired,
>   agreeable, and likeable, connected with sensual desire and provocative
>   of lust. Having conducted himself well in body, speech, and mind, on
>   the dissolution of the body, after death, he might reappear in a happy
>   destination, in the heavenly world in the retinue of the gods of the
>   Thirty-three; and there, surrounded by a group of nymphs in the
>   Nandana Grove, he would enjoy himself, provided and endowed with the
>   five cords of divine sensual pleasure.
>
> MN 75

Comment: Making lots of money might turn one into Donald Trump but if that's heaven then that might have to do why it's best to become enlightened.